MockK io.mockk.MockKException: Either mockType or objToCopy should not be null
I am testing a service which has another service as a dependency. I want to inject a spy of the dependent service so that I can either call actual methods of dependent service or set expectation to return a mock response in a different case.
Here is how I am initialising the spy and SUT service.
private lateinit var scoringService: ScoringService

@SpyK 
private lateinit var underwritingServiceSpy: UnderwritingService

... <other variables to be injected as mocks>

@BeforeEach
fun setUp() {

        ...

        underwritingServiceSpy = UnderwritingService(
            underwritingRepositoryMock,
            contractServiceMock,
            MockTransactionHelper.SINGLETON,
            clock,
            objectMapperMock,
            businessServiceMock
        )


        scoringService =
            ScoringService(
                underwritingRepositoryMock,
                apolloQueryExecutor,
                contractPricingClientSupplier,
                ...
                underwritingServiceSpy
            )
}

However, when trying to run the test cases I am getting the following error
io.mockk.MockKException: Either mockType or objToCopy should not be null
at io.mockk.impl.instantiation.AbstractMockFactory.spyk(AbstractMockFactory.kt:81)
at io.mockk.impl.annotations.JvmMockInitializer.createSpyK(JvmMockInitializer.kt:127)
at io.mockk.impl.annotations.JvmMockInitializer.assignSpyK(JvmMockInitializer.kt:117)
at io.mockk.impl.annotations.JvmMockInitializer.initMock(JvmMockInitializer.kt:50)
at io.mockk.impl.annotations.JvmMockInitializer.initAnnotatedMocks(JvmMockInitializer.kt:24)
at io.mockk.junit5.MockKExtension.postProcessTestInstance(MockKExtension.kt:238)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$10(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:377)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.executeAndMaskThrowable(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:382)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$11(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:377)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:179)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1625)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
at java.base/java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.forEachRemaining(StreamSpliterators.java:310)
at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:735)
at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:734)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:762)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeTestInstancePostProcessors(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:376)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance$6(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:289)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:288)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$4(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:278)
at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:364)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$5(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:277)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.TestInstancesProvider.getTestInstances(TestInstancesProvider.java:31)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$prepare$0(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:105)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:104)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:68)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$prepare$2(NodeTestTask.java:123)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.prepare(NodeTestTask.java:123)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:90)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:147)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:127)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:90)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:55)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:102)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:53)
at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:57)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:232)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:55)

I searched around for any clues but can't find any information.
What I expect is that as I am injecting a Spy so when I don't create the stubbing block using every{} then the call should go the actual method in the dependent service, and when I use subbing block with every{} expression in the test then it should return stubbed response.

My guess is that it's unclear whether the @Spyk or @BeforeEach annotation is done first, and if @BeforeEach is performed afterwards then underwritingServiceSpy will not actually be a spy because you've just reassigned it to a non-spy object. Try either initializing the variable at the point of declaration, or leave out the @Spy annotation and initialize it in the BeforeEach function as spykk<...>(...).

@k314159 That was exactly the issue. I removed @Spy annotation and initialized the spy inside @BeforeEach with spyk<...>(...) and it worked. Thanks for your help.

I had the same issue and I got mine working using @SpykBean instead of @Spyk
import com.ninjasquad.springmockk.SpykBean

@SpykBean
private lateinit var foo: Foo


This may be inapplicable to the OP as there is no indication they're using Spring. Nevertheless, this could be a good answer for any future readers that are using Spring.
